# How to change NSNumber value in XCode while debugging?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, nsnumber

My class has a member variable which is a NSNumber, like so:

```
@interface C : NSObject {
    NSNumber* _n;
}
```

During debugging, I am stopped at a breakpoint, and I want to change the value of the NSNumber.  How can I do it?

I tried the XCode variables window, but that does not work.

I tried the XCode debug console, for example

```
expr _n = @1
```

but that gives the bizarre message **error: assigning to 'NSNumber *' from incompatible type 'NSNumber *'** -- no kidding! Try it.

I also tried

```
expr _n = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
```

but that gives the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
(lldb) expr -- _n = (NSNumber *)[NSNumber numberWithInt:123]
(NSNumber *) $0 = 0x0000000000007b83 (int)123
(lldb) po _n
(NSNumber *) $1 = 0x0000000000007b83 123
```

The `--` is required to mark the end of command options and beginning of "raw" input.

Strictly speaking, this does not change the value of the existing `NSNumber`, but assigns a new `NSNumber` object to `_n`. But `NSNumber` objects are immutable, so changing their value is not possible anyway.

Comment: Can you share any links on good tutorials for learning the debugger in general?

Comment: @JRG-Developer: I must admit that for me working with the new lldb is often "try and error". But perhaps this thread helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974455/lldb-where-is-the-official-extensive-complete-documentation.

Comment: Looks like boxing syntax works here too. I tried `po @(1.5)` and got `(NSNumber *) $1 = 0x000000010054a520 1.5`

Comment: @nielsbot: I had tried only `@123`, which does not work in the debugger. So thanks for the feedback, I can add that to the answer if that is OK with you.

Comment: Sure, I don't mind. I just assumed the parentheses were required--I've never used any other syntax.

Comment: @nielsbot: `po @(1.5)` works in the debugger, but assigning to a variable with `expr -- _n = @(1.3)` gives a syntax error.

Comment: I got something even weirder: `expr _n = @(1.5)` gives `error: assigning to 'NSNumber *' from incompatible type 'NSNumber *'`

Comment: @nielsbot: Yes, that is what I meant. The error message is really weird, it is the same that the OP already observed in his question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this line:

```
po _n = @(123)
```